# Redirect specific URL to another URL on another subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, dns, subdomain, redirect

I have 5 URLs on a subdomain website `http://subdomain.example.com`, and I want them to redirect to 5 other URLs on my main website, `https://www.example.com/`.

Important: URLs do NOT have the same structure!

Example:

1. `http://subdomain.example.com/url1` should redirect to `https://www.example.com/ipsum`
2. `http://subdomain.example.com/url2` should redirect to `https://www.example.com/lorem`
3. etc.

How can I handle that?

**UPDATE:**

There is a `play` folder (name of the subdomain) which contains the subdomain website files and a `htdocs` folder which contains the www website files.

Here is the `.htaccess` file in my `play` folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What did you try already? Did you search about the other similar questions?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek yes i did, but all I see is cases when the structure is the same (from : subdomain.example.com/lorem to www.example.com/lorem)

Comment: Where does the subdomain point to in relation to the main domain on the filesystem? Or are they completely unrelated? Do you have any existing directives in your `.htaccess` file(s)?

Comment: @MrWhite it's the same domain but they seem unrelated. In my FTP, i got : 
- a `play` folder (name of the subdomain) which contains the subdomain website files
- a `htdocs` folder which contains the www website files.

Here is the `.htaccess` file in my `play` folder

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the subdomain has it's own `.htaccess` file, you don't need to specify the hostname as part of the redirect. And since you already have mod_rewrite directives in the subdomain's `.htaccess` file, you should also use mod_rewrite for these redirects (to avoid conflicts). Otherwise, you'll need to specify these redirects one-by-one.

Try the following at the top of your subdomain's `/play/.htaccess` file. Note that this needs to go *before* the existing directives in the file.

```
# Specific redirects
RewriteRule ^url1$ https://www.example.com/ipsum [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^url2$ https://www.example.com/lorem [R=302,L]
```

The above would match a request for `http://subdomain.example.com/url1` and redirect accordingly, etc.

Note that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (regular expression) does not start with a slash when used in a per-directory (`.htaccess`) context.

Note that these are 302 (temporary) redirects. Change them to 301 (permanent) - if that is the intention - only once you have confirmed they are working OK (to avoid caching issues).

Comment: Spent an hour trying to get a simple redirect to work on a subdirectory and your post works for me. This is a life saver! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Redirect 301 http://subdomain.example.com/url1 https://www.example.com/ipsum
Redirect 301 http://subdomain.example.com/url2 https://www.example.com/lorem
```

Comment: Since the OP has already stated they are using mod_rewrite in this context, it is advisable to use mod_rewrite for these redirects as well; not a mod_alias `Redirect` directive. mod_rewrite executes first, despite the order of directives, so the front-controller unnecessarily rewrites the URL _before_ the redirect occurs.